# Ajax request Gets redirected (302 response) (due to passport i guess)

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, passport.js, csrf

so I'm trying to send a formula with Ajax, before using passport for the Signup it was working, after using passport, the POST request to "/ajout-membre" gets redirected to "/" with a GET, explain more my code.

```
                            var url = "http://localhost:8080/ajout-membre";
                               $.ajax({
                                 url: url,
                                 headers: {"X-CSRF-Token": $("#csrf1").val()},
                                 data: JSON.stringify(sentinfo),
                                 xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
                                 crossDomain: true,
                                 type: 'POST',
                                 contentType: 'application/json',
                                 success: function(data){
                                    //here something to do;
                                    if(data=="membre_existant")
                                        alert("membre existant");

                                    else{
                                        alert("Une erreur inconnue s'est produite");
                                    }
                                 }
                               });
```

The "/ajout-membre" just for the test:

```
    router.post('/ajout-membre',function(req,res){
     res.send(JSON.stringify("Done"));

     });
```

how you can help me to fixe this, i just want him to got to that root that's all

Comment: exactly what is shown in the Developer Tools Network tab for this request.

Comment: Yeah, can you show the source of the page it gets redirected to?

Comment: here 2 screenshots: hope this will help:
http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=517108Screenshotfrom20161005001759.png
http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=158481Screenshotfrom20161005001648.png

@PawnStar there is a GET for the "/" page but i don't get redirect (the alert is shown as in the code, like the request succeded but no i don't get "don" as data i get html code of the page)

Comment: I meant the source of the response.  If you click on the / line in the network tab, and then show the response section: https://i.gyazo.com/68f8bae695354727be83d084f517496c.png

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out if that request has any odd cookies or anything attached to it that would cause passport to think it needs to be redirected, and was hoping that would give us a hint of whether that request is considered authenticated or not.

Comment: @PawnStar so in the Response i got the code of the "dashboard" page, the actual page.    http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=566705Screenshotfrom20161005063047.png

Comment: @PawnStar i uploaded it on a file: 
https://mega.nz/#!LVEX0JBb!MjdqOow_Adrq3CeqvPWZkBODdSgA8oq3N_-c4ROdqnE
:)

in cookies Tab i got this: connect.sid:"s:LRcp-t6QT78owR7JhGaTUhdisa_dbaxi.AEI/d1btWOcN5DrWVwVIKde27AEa9w1V1Ze6AWpJT18"

Comment: Can you add more routing code? There is another middleware somewhere that does the redirect, or maybe the router you have here is not bound to root. Passport should redirect only after authentication and only if you told it to do so.

Comment: It doesn't look like any sort of login page, so the ajax request is probably not getting redirected by Passport.  I'd guess either another route like @vesse said or somewhere in the passport.serializeUser or passport.deserializeUser methods.